# How to split data in R by particular criteria?

Tags: r

I have a data set with 3 columns, one with Unique code for people, another with age groups, another with which Branch they are signed up at.

How do I then split this data into 2 groups where both groups have the same distribution of age as well as the same distribution of Branch they are signed up at (both groups should have roughly equal % of different age group and different Branches as well).

Is there a way to do this more accurately and not group by age group at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls provide a reproducible set of (toy) data

Comment: And the division should be random, right? or can it be a judgemental sample

Comment: It can be both as long as both data set after split has the same distribution of those 2 criteria's. Ideally it should allow me to split 2/3 1/3 or 1/2 1/2 etc.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Okay give me a moment

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann it seems that I cannot upload an excel file. To create the data set you can call the Branches A to E and use a random generator for the age and replace the unique code with just numerics?

Comment: Upload your excel file on drive and share link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

---

data creation.

- x is something unique id
- `y_grp` is group_id with four different categories
- `z_grp` is grp id with three different categories

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                 y_grp = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, T),
                 z_grp = sample(LETTERS[8:10], 100, T))
```

---

Division into two samples

```
sample1 <- df %>% group_by(y_grp, z_grp) %>%
  slice_sample(prop = 0.5) %>% ungroup()

sample2 <- anti_join(df, sample1, by = "x")
```

---

Check counts in these two samples

```
library(janitor)
sample1 %>% tabyl(y_grp, z_grp) %>% adorn_totals(c("row", "col"))
 y_grp  H  I  J Total
     A  3  5  4    12
     B  5  3  7    15
     C  3  5  2    10
     D  3  2  5    10
 Total 14 15 18    47

sample2 %>% tabyl(y_grp, z_grp) %>% adorn_totals(c("row", "col"))
 y_grp  H  I  J Total
     A  4  6  5    15
     B  6  3  7    16
     C  4  6  2    12
     D  3  2  5    10
 Total 17 17 19    53
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the code and it does work but I have to sort of change the proportion to get the even split of data. Is there a way to get around the fact that sample1 will always take the lower number of the split? E.g. Sample1 takes 3 6 4 in group A to get the totals aligned? But thanks so much, this was really helpful!

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Please accept the answer as per usual guidelines of SO and for future reference too.  As regards your additional requirement please edit the question accordingly or post a new question