# Randomly split a sample into 3 representative groups

Tags: r, sampling

I have a list of customers (n=23,805) that I need to allocate into 3 groups.
Each group should be representative of the overall customer characteristics:

- state
- gender
- age group
- customer type

I'm using this solution that works to divide the list in 2 equally sized groups:
[how to split data in R by particular criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208273/how-to-split-data-in-r-by-particular-criteria)

This is what I have so far

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- [list of customer info]

s1 <- data %>% group_by(customer_type, state, gender, age_group) %>%
    slice_sample(prop = 0.33333) %>% ungroup()
```

This gives me the first sample representative of the customer list at the right size (n=7,663)

Now to figure out how to split the remainder

```
#grab the remainder
remainder <- anti_join(data, s1, by = "number")
```

given that the remainder is actually two-thirds, it should be just a matter of splitting it 2 representative groups:

```
s2 <- remainder %>% group_by(customer_type, state, gender, age_group) %>%
    slice_sample(prop = 0.5) %>% ungroup()

remainder <- anti_join(remainder, s2, by = "number")
s3 <- remainder
```

However, the sample size for s2 and s3 are 7,900 and 8,242.
The problem is that the basis of representation for s2 is based on *two-thirds* of the list rather than the whole.

How do I ensure s2 is representative of the whole list and excludes anyone randomly allocated to s1?

**NOTE 1:**

Thanks to Roman's suggestion, I've looked at the caret package which seems to work:

```
library(caret)

a1 <- createDataPartition(paste(data$customer_type, data$state, data$gender, data$age_group), p = 0.3333, list = FALSE)
s1 <- data[a1, ]
a2 <- createDataPartition(paste(data$customer_type, data$state, data$gender, data$age_group)[-a1], p = 0.3333, list = FALSE)
s2 <- data[a2, ]
a3 <- createDataPartition(paste(data$customer_type, data$state, data$gender, data$age_group)[-a1][-a2], p = 0.3333, list = FALSE)
s3 <- data[a3, ]
```

However the 3 samples are not equally sized: s1 = 8,126, s2 = 5,345, s3 = 10,383. I think the issue is that not all customers have data in each field.

**NOTE 2:**

I've subset the my dataframe to include only those with data in the relevant fields (n=22,834). So the 3 samples should be approx. 7,612 records.

Re-running the code from Note 1 achieves s1 = 7,728, s2 = 5,118, s3 = 3,409 which is better but not equal and not the total sample that could be grouped.

Comment: have you checked the rsample or caret packages?